# Got lost on this code and cant make it work

Tags: actionscript-3

Im getting an weird error about constructions definitions that i have no idea what means.
Im studing this for a test.I think the problem is on the functions but im not sure.
Its a code from an game (pretty simple one) that you have to move your player from point b to point a without letting the falling asteroids touch you.
Thanks in advance.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

         var up:Boolean;
         var down:Boolean;
         var left:Boolean;
         var right:Boolean;
         var vel:Number;
         var velInimigo:Number;
         var sentidoX:Number;
         var sentidoY:Number;
         var d:MovieClip;
         var txt1:MovieClip;
         var chegada:MovieClip;
         var player:MovieClip;
         var inimigos:Array;
         var i:int;
         var mc:MovieClip;





function MainTimeline()
        {
            addFrameScript(0, frame1);
            return;
        }

         function OnKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.W:
                {
                    up = true;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.S:
                {
                    down = true;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.A:
                {
                    left = true;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.D:
                {
                    right = true;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

function OnKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent) : void
        {
            switch(event.keyCode)
            {
                case Keyboard.W:
                {
                    up = false;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.S:
                {
                    down = false;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.A:
                {
                    left = false;
                    break;
                }
                case Keyboard.D:
                {
                    right = false;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
function OnFrame(event:Event) : void
        {
            var loc3: = null;
            var loc4: = null;
            if (up)
            {
                sentidoY = -1;
            }
            else if (down)
            {
                sentidoY = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sentidoY = 0;
            }
            if (left)
            {
                sentidoX = -1;
            }
            else if (right)
            {
                sentidoX = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                sentidoX = 0;
            }
            if (sentidoX == 1 && sentidoY == 0)
            {
                player.rotation = 0 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == 1 && sentidoY == 1)
            {
                player.rotation = 45 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == 0 && sentidoY == 1)
            {
                player.rotation = 90 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == -1 && sentidoY == 1)
            {
                player.rotation = 135 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == -1 && sentidoY == 0)
            {
                player.rotation = 180 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == -1 && sentidoY == -1)
            {
                player.rotation = 225 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == 0 && sentidoY == -1)
            {
                player.rotation = 270 + 90;
            }
            else if (sentidoX == 1 && sentidoY == -1)
            {
                player.rotation = 315 + 90;
            }
            player.x = player.x + vel * sentidoX;
            player.y = player.y + vel * sentidoY;
            var loc2: = 0 ;
            while (loc2 < inimigos.length)
            {

                loc3 = inimigos[loc2];
                loc3.y = loc3.y + loc3.vel;
                loc3.rotation = loc3.rotation + loc3.rotVel;
                if (loc3.hitTestObject(player))
                {
                    loc4 = new GameOverMC();
                    stage.addChild(loc4);
                    loc4.x = stage.stage.width / 2;
                    loc4.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
                    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTERFRAME, OnFrame);
                }
                if (loc3.y > stage.stageHeight)
                {
                    loc3.y = -loc3.height;
                }
                loc2++;
            }
            if (player.hitTestObject(chegada))
            {
                if (txt1 == null)
                {
                    txt1 = new VitoriaMC();
                    stage.addChild(txt1);
                    txt1.x = stage.stage.width / 2;
                    txt1.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
                }
            }
            d.x = d.x + d.vel * d.sx;
            d.y = d.y + d.vel * d.sy;
            if (d.x >= stage.stageWidth - d.width / 2 || d.x <= d.width / 2)
            {
                d.sx = -d.sx;
            }
            if (d.y >= stage.stageHeight - d.height / 2 || d.y <= d.height / 2)
            {
                d.sy = -d.sy;
            }
            return;
        }
function frame1()
        {
            vel = 5;
            velInimigo = 2;
            sentidoX = 0;
            sentidoY = 0;
            d = new DemoMC();
            d.vel = 1;
            d.sx = 1;
            d.sy = 1;
            d.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            d.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            txt1 = null;
            chegada = new ChegadaMC();
            player = new PlayerMC();
            inimigos = new Array();
            stage.addChild(d);
            stage.addChild(chegada);
            stage.addChild(player);
            player.x = player.width / 2;
            player.y = stage.stageHeight - player.height / 2;
            chegada.x = stage.stageWidth - chegada.width;
            chegada.y = 0;
            i = 0;
            while (i < 60)
            {

                mc = new AstroMC();
                stage.addChild(mc);
                inimigos.push(mc);
                mc.x = 100 + Math.random() * (600 - mc.width);
                mc.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                mc.rotVel = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
                mc.vel = Math.random() * 3 + 1;
                var loc1: = i;
                var loc2: = i + 1;
                loc1.i = loc2;
            }
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEYDOWN, OnKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEYUP, OnKeyUp);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTERFRAME, OnFrame);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: can you post the exact error you are getting

Comment: Are you decompiling a swf?  Names like `loc3` and `loc4` are similar to what you would get out of a decompiler.

Comment: yes im decompiling to study for a test

Comment: If you're seeing stuff like `loc3` and `loc4` it means those things have been protected by the coder and aren't usable in anyone's code as they are (maybe geniuses can do it).. Better to start with your own plan take each step of plan slowly. Many tutorials out there on how to 1. Move objects around screen via keyboard/mouse `enterFrame`, `keyboardEvent`, 2 Detect if graphic touched another `hitTestObject` or `hitTestPoint`. Then you already have a moveable player with system to detect if asteroid touched and from there you can try add another feature

Comment: Thanks VC.One,you are a true bro!

Comment: This is the second time i cause trouble for you sorry \;

Comment: I don't know what you mean by trouble. I'm just telling you no one makes a working program using lines like `var loc3: = null;` it's a warning sign that this code is made redundant to copy & pasting (and possibly selling) by somebody else. Your question & this code cannot happen. To make it work would take more effort than just creating a concept clone from scratch plus then you would know what everything does since you put it there. Just keep trying. Also analysing and adjusting from the tuts you read just to learn how those things work. Experiment much and your AS3 skills will get better

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile since i have played with AS3 but i see a few odd things one being the

```
loc1.i = loc2;
```

near the bottom

what is "i" in relation to loc1? and this is in a while loop using i but never increments it so it seems like an infinite loop

again i could be wrong its been quite some time.